# System of equations on $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Knowing that $a,b,c,d,e,f \in \mathbb{Z}$ solve the system:
$$
\begin{align}
18&=cf \\
27&=ce+bf \\
28&=af+be+cd \\
22&=f+ae+bd+c \\
11&=e+b+ad \\
5&=a+d
\end{align}
$$

I want to find solution without using trail and error approach...

Comment: Given the relatively small search-space for trial and error ($c, f$ can have only 10 values), why do you want to not use that approach? If there were algebra you could do to solve this system, it would also solve it as a *real* system...but does the real system have only one solution? Who knows? (Indeed, are you sure that there's only one integer solution?)

Comment: The number of possible values is large... I am interested in the solution process of this system, the solution itself is not so important... What do you mean by "If there were algebra"? (this system has a solution.. don't know if its one, and what happen in a real system)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system of equations basically states
$$\begin{gather}
(1+ax+bx^2+cx^3)(1+dx+ex^2+fx^3)=p(x)\\
\text{where}\quad
p(x)=1+5x+11x^2+22x^3+28x^4+27x^5+18x^6
\end{gather}$$
where $x$ is just a formal variable -- you do not solve for $x$.

So basically you have to factor the polynomial $p(x)$ into two cubic polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}$. The complete factorization into irreducibles is
$$p(x) = (1+x+2x^2+3x^3)\underbrace{(1+3x)(1+x+2x^2)}_{1+4x+5x^2+6x^3}$$
so there are only two possibilities for matching the cubic factors:
$$(a,b,c;d,e,f) \in \{(1,2,3;4,5,6),(4,5,6;1,2,3),\}$$
Normally, we would additionally have to consider the possibility of having
a common factor such as $\pm1$ distributed among the polynomial factors,
but the problem statement has constant terms fixed at $1$
which simplifies things a bit.

Comment: wow... but how did you know the factors of the polynom?

Comment: I was lazy and used Pari/GP for factoring. Given enough perseverance, I could have found the factors by hand, but that was not part of the question. Wikipedia has articles on [polynomial factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_factorization)

Comment: For a related problem without restrictions on the solution set, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1295650)

Comment: Well spotted! And absolute agreement on what you wrote in your comment under my question about **giving context**.

Answer (score 1):

As John observed, there are $10$ different cases for $c$ and $f$. That uses up the first equation. You can then use the last and the second (now linear) equation to eliminate, say, $d$ and $e$. That leaves you with $3$ quadratic equations in $a$ and $b$. You can solve the fifth equation (now linear in $b$) for $b$ and substitute the result into the third or fourth equation to obtain a fourth or third order equation for $a$, respectively. For any integer values of $a$ that satisfy that equation (at most $4$, obtainable without trial and error), the corresponding values of $b$, $d$ and $e$ follow by substitution.

Comment: I am looking for a solution without trails....

Comment: @GrigoryIlizirov: I think you mean "trials", and I think you'll have to define that. If you reduce the equations modulo some prime and find that the residue of one of the variables can only take one of two values, is it a trial to consider those two cases separately? Considering that on the face of it this system looks like it could require a big computer search, treating ten different cases that allow you to easily solve it by hand isn't that much of a trial.

Comment: Apart from figuring $12$ different cases for $(c,f)$, I fully agree

Comment: @ccorn: Funny, I thought I checked that, but you're right, there are $12$.

Comment: It seems the OP actually [wants to solve a factoring problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1379023/75794), so my answer turns out to be of little use to him. This underlines the importance of **giving context**. That said, if black-box factoring tools are disallowed, then joriki's answer is currently the most suitable one. Upvoted.